# How to reducing container recreating time using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

from the last few days i was trying to reduce my node application downtime when deploying my new code change.

Im using docker for this and im very much near to the goal but im stuck on the final step where container gets recreate when running
`docker-compose up`
command, as the container takes around 30-40 seconds to recreate itself. Now for that 30-40 seconds my application is down which is unacceptable.

To do this i was searching for some internal commands of docker compose but found nothing.
One thing i tried is to create new container rather than recreating the existing one but for this i need to expose the same port 8081 which is not possible. Also there is no way to update the ports of running container.

Please let me know if anybody have other solutions or if im missing something in my process. Thanks

Comment: What are you doing now?  The one important thing you can do is `docker-compose build` to rebuild the image(s) before you recreate the container(s); I'd expect the actual process of restarting a container to be relatively quick.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and some debugging details on what you are doing and seeing. As written, it's not clear that this is an issue with docker vs your application being run inside docker.